# Chrome Extension. How to add new custom column in chrome network tab in developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to create extension which edits chrome dev tools functionality?
for example to add new custom column in 'Network' tab?

Or is it possible to listen in my custom extension that particular request has been clicked in network tab? and fire some function when that event triggers?

Comment: Devtools doesn't offer this feature. You can suggest it on https://crbug.com.